# SQL Server - Group by returns same information

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, grouping

I am use to how MySQL works with `Group_Concat` so having difficulty understanding how SQL server works with group concat. I can't group only by `PPNumber` for the `xml path` grouping since I select the `Bx` value.

Is there a way to make the delimited listing of Bx values group based on the `pp.[PPNumber]  as PartNumber` column or is there a better way to get the `Bxs` to group only by `PPNumber` column within the `xml path` grouping?

```
SELECT  
pp.[PPNumber]  as PartNumber,
COUNT(PSN) as ActualCount, 
replace((SELECT b.Bx AS [data()]
        FROM def.dbo.[boxes] b
        Group By b.[PPNumber]  ,b.Bx
        ORDER BY b.Bx
        FOR xml path('')), ' ', ',') as Bxs

FROM def.dbo.[packtable] p
JOIN (SELECT Bx, [PPNumber] FROM def.dbo.[boxes] WHERE (CONCAT(Completed, ' 
  ', CompletedTime) > @sDate AND CONCAT(Completed,' ',  CompletedTime) < 
  @eDate)) b on p.Bx= b.Bx
JOIN def.dbo.[PPNumlist] pp on b.[PPNumber]  = pp.[PPNumber]  

GROUP BY pp.[PPNumber]
ORDER BY pp.[PPNumber]  ;
```

[image]

Comment: It would help out if you could post some sample data, since it's very difficult to reverse engineer from your results and sql statement. I suspect the issue is that the subquery in your SELECT clause is not correlated to the main query (no relationship between `def.dbo.boxes` in your subquery's WHERE clause to your main query's two tables). I suspect also that the subquery is unnecessary since you are already joining the boxes table in. Sample data would help clarify though.

Comment: The sample data is in the image. What other information should I provide to help then? @JNevill

Comment: @JNevill is asking that you post a sample of what you are starting with, not just the result(s) that you're looking for. Looking at the query devoid of the context makes the task much harder.

Comment: Essentially, a short example of what your `packtable`, `boxes` table, and `pplist` table look like. Data that fits that desired results, so records containing parts 1112-1 and 1112-2 and boxes 1,2,3,4,5. We'll then know what your data looks like in the database, and from your current question, how you want it to look. Then we can help write out the SQL to get you there.

Comment: Oh ok. Didn't think to show each table's information initially. Sorry about that. I ended up playing more and got a function to pass in each `PN` value and got each delimited Bx list to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JNevil metioned the subquery wasn't correlating to the main query. This I agree but I didn't know the best way to go about it. However, I tested using a Function and it worked out correctly.

All I did was pass in the PN and Date ranges and it worked!

```
SELECT  
pp.[PPNumber]  as PartNumber,
COUNT(PSN) as ActualCount, 
def.dbo.udf_Get_PackedBoxListByPN(pp.[PPNumber], @sDate,@eDate) as Bxs
```